# This application is not allowed to create application tokens "How to Fix"

Tags: linkedin-api

I need a help on REST API for linkedin profile. I tried a lot but am unable to pull those details.

Can any one help me on the api of linkedin which helps to retrieve the profile name, profile image..

"https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=7828imadgwgbpl&client_secret=tA5gtnD8nmorio3m"

with this GET method am getting this error message

"{
"error": "access_denied",
"error_description": "This application is not allowed to create application tokens"
}"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linkedin "this application is not allowed to create application tokens"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50626514/linkedin-this-application-is-not-allowed-to-create-application-tokens)

Comment: I have already refererred. The main action here is unable to generate the access token, am getting the error message as "{
"error": "access_denied",
"error_description": "This application is not allowed to create application tokens"
}"

Comment: And that's the same exact error as the other poster is getting, and the answer to that question tells you how to fix the issue, which is why your post is a duplicate.

Comment: 3-legged OAuth is  the default for a Linkedin app

Comment: @imrankhan-k did you managed to get your bearer token please?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, LinkedIn doesn't automatically enable 2-legged authorization.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin/context

> If your application needs to access APIs that are not member specific, use the Client Credential Flow. Your application cannot access these APIs by default. Learn more about LinkedIn Developer Enterprise products to request permission to the Client Credential Flow.

Comment: So what is the solution please? Isn't it kind of basic to request by default a token API to start developing?

Comment: @hzitoun (unfortunately) I manually get the refresh token and save it, then I kept the remaining flow automatically.