# Error_description: 'This application is not allowed to create application tokens'

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api

I'm automating posts to linkedin. As is a server app communication I'm using the 2leg flow Oath docs explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin/context

The function I'm using is:

```
var request = require('request')
var linkObj = {
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        client_id: {CLIENT_ID},
        client_secret: {CLIENT_SECRET}
    };
request.post('https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken', linkObj, function(err, data){
  console.log(data)
})
```

OUTPUT:

{error: 'access_denied',error_description: 'This application is not allowed to create application tokens'}

In theory is all credentials required are default and can not be changed as well there is no info showed in the app.

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50626514/linkedin-this-application-is-not-allowed-to-create-application-tokens

Comment: The post is looking to post as a partner. I'm already using that documentation; still not working

Comment: [It also says](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v2/oauth2-client-credentials-flow) "By default, your application will not have the ability to use LinkedIn's client credentials flow.  Contact us to have your application granted permission to use this flow." If you have already done that, you should get back in touch with them and tell them it's not working.