# LinkedIn API Integration to fetch company posts

Tags: php, node.js, angular, linkedin-api

I am working to integration LinkedIn API to fetch company posts.

I have followed document with below linkedIn link:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v2/oauth2-client-credentials-flow

Getting error:

> access_denied: This application is not allowed to create application
>   tokens.

and also I am accessing API of activity feeds (https://api.linkedin.com/v2/activityFeeds?q=networkShares) but getting below error:

> Not enough permissions to access: GET-networkShares /activityFeeds

can anyone describe whole steps for the same?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [linkedin "this application is not allowed to create application tokens"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50626514/linkedin-this-application-is-not-allowed-to-create-application-tokens)

Answer (score 2):

You have to contact the LinkedIn to grant the permission to your application

This is the message from LinkedIn

> By default, your application will not have the ability to use
>   LinkedIn's client credentials flow.  Contact us to have your
>   application granted permission to use this flow.

[image]

> Once you have successfully registered an Application and met the other
>   requirements for a particular API, you will be given Access
>   Credentials for your Application. “Access Credentials” means the
>   necessary security keys, secrets, tokens, and other credentials to
>   access the applicable APIs. The Access Credentials enable us to
>   associate your API activity with your Application and the Members
>   using it. All activities that occur using your Access Credentials are
>   your responsibility. Keep your Access Credentials secret. Do not sell,
>   share, transfer, or sublicense them to any other party other than your
>   employees or independent contractors in accordance with Section 3.1
>   below. Do not try to circumvent them and do not require your users to
>   obtain their own Access Credentials to use your Application (for
>   example, in an attempt to circumvent call limits).

Please refer their [API Terms of Use](https://legal.linkedin.com/api-terms-of-use) for more help. Especially section 2

- Access to the APIs