# Linked Standardized Data API v2/titles Access

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to use the Linkedin standardized data APIs. But its not clear how to permission myself to this via the Developer Portal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/standardized-data/titles#get_all

```
curl -X GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/titles -H 'Authorization: Bearer BEARER_TOKEN'
```

Returns:

{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access: GET /titles","status":403}

Whereas

```
curl -X GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me -H 'Authorization: Bearer BEARER_TOKEN'
```

Returns
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
With Payload

Looks like LinkedIn needs to enable the client_credentials flow but not obvious where to request this: [linkedin "this application is not allowed to create application tokens"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50626514/linkedin-this-application-is-not-allowed-to-create-application-tokens) ?

Comment: Did you find out in the end?